# How do I use a form in a class as a new form in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagrid

When I use Ceghozzadas.DataGridCeg.DataSource=... it works fine, but as a new form it doesn't.
Any help please? :)

```
Public Class CegHozzadas
 Private Sub CegHozzadas_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim DataGridFill As New DataGrid
        DataGridFill.DataGridFill()
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataGrid
     Public Sub DataGridFill()
         Dim thisform As New CegHozzadas
         thisform.DataGridCeg.DataSource = ...
    end sub
end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the flow of your code.

You have the `CegHozzadas` class, which I'll call "Form A" as an example. Form A loads, creating a new `DataGrid` and calling `DataGridFill()` on it.

When you call `DataGridFill()`, it makes a *brand new* `CegHozzadas`, which is NOT the same form as Form A. You then try to set your *new* `DataGridCeg`'s data source to... something.

Do you see the issue here? You've created two forms while presumably only wanting to change `DataGridCeg`'s data source on Form A. You don't see the data source changing because you're modifying the data source of a control on an entirely different form. This entirely different form isn't even being displayed on the screen, it just exists in the background.

If all you want to do is set the data source of `DataGridCeg` on a new form, then simply set it during the form's constructor, which you've already stated you know works.

```
Public Class CegHozzadas
    Public Sub New()
        DataGridCeg.DataSource = ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you absolutely *must* go through your `DataGrid` class's `DataGridFill()` method, then you can pass your form as an argument to `DataGridFill()`, but I highly advise against this. You shouldn't have to leave the code-behind of `CegHozzadas` to do data binding here.

```
Public Class CegHozzadas
    Private Sub CegHozzadas_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim DataGridFill As New DataGrid
        DataGridFill.DataGridFill(Me)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DataGrid
     Public Sub DataGridFill(MyForm As CegHozzadas)
         MyForm.DataGridCeg.DataSource = ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank you for helping!